# Why does Scipy's fit() function for gamma distribution producing a totally dissimilar distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to use `scipy`'s fit function to fit a gamma distribution to observed data. The histogram for the observed data is below:

[image]

The mean and variance are

```
print("mean",np.mean(observed_data)) # mean 0.427611176580073
print("Var",np.var(observed_data)) # Var 0.6898193689790143
```

However, if I use `scipy.stats.gamma.fit()` to fit this observed data to a gamma distribution and then sample again from that distribution, the mean and variance are totally different:

[image]

I know that `scipy` is fitting based on MLE, but I'm not understanding the intuition behind why these key statistics are so off - the mean and variance are totally different. In fact, I can get much better results simply running this through my own solver:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from typing import List
def fit_gamma_distribution(data: List[float]):
    mean = np.mean(data)
    variance = np.var(data)

    def equations(p):
        k, theta = p
        return (k * theta - mean, k * theta **2 - variance)
    solved_k, solved_theta = fsolve(equations, (1,1))

    if np.isclose(np.array([solved_k * solved_theta]), np.array([mean]), rtol=0.01):
        return fsolve(equations, (1,1))

k, theta = fit_gamma_distribution(observed_data)

new_dist = np.random.gamma(shape=k, scale=
theta, size=len(observed_data))
plt.hist(new_dist, alpha= 0.5, bins=40)
plt.hist(observed_data, alpha=0.2, bins=40)
plt.xlim(0,5)
plt.title(f"New sampled distribution: μ = {round(np.mean(new_dist),2)} observed μ = {round(np.mean(observed_data), 2)}")
```

[image]

It's a much better fit than the `scipy` one in my opinion. Why is this the case?

Comment: Did you compare the actual likelihoods of your fit and the `scipy` fit? Which one is higher?

Comment: Can you add some data to the example?